# Text view displays Arabic characters as question marks "?????"

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-typeface, arabic-support

I'm working on an android app that displays a `textviews` with mixed Arabic and English words;

the app displays Arabic text that I wrote inside Java classes as question marks ????? here is a **screenshot:**

[image]

**The Code:**

```
if(tCat.equals("StandardT_")){
     serviceLine="Operations / خدمات عامة";
 }
tv.setText(serviceLine);
```

**what I have tried:**

1. [Decoding characters in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055020/decoding-characters-in-android) 
   and no its not the same question and the answers didn't help.
2. [How to support Arabic text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813) 
   I'm using a new version that supports Arabic and I also tried the answer like adding `Farsi` Class or using `ArabicUtilities` classes but that didn't work ether
3. I also tried to encode String into utf-8

   try {
                serviceLine= URLEncoder.encode(serviceLine, "utf-8");}
           catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                          e.printStackTrace();
           }

and that didn't work!

4. also tried using multiple fonts but not a single Typeface solved the problem.

So I'm kind of stuck here, any ideas?

***Edit:*** 
After I closed android studio and reopened the app all of the text that I wrote inside the Java classes turned to question marks! Even though I tried to write it again, once I closed the project and reopened it, it displays the Arabic text as question marks inside the Java classes before even I run the application and this is really awkward!

Comment: try to  use BIDI in your app it will make a lot easier http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html

Comment: Set Android Studio encoding mode correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the **file encoding** of the file that **contains** the arabic text to **UTF-8**.

This is how you change file encoding from inside [Android-Studio](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/).